# passing text value to ajax function on clicking submit button

Tags: php, ajax

I have form which consists of a text field (id="txt1")
and a submit button(id="submit"). Ajax function 'showhint()' is called on 'onclick' event of submit button.

```
<form action="">  
<input type="text" id="txt1"   />
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="showhint()"/>
</form>
```

And ajax function

```
    function showhint(){
var xmlhttp;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmllhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txthint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
        }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
```

Here gethint.php is page where showhint() function does its work and targeted div to write ajax respone is "txthint" .
what I want is to pass text value(form's) to ajax function. Is there any easy way?
Waiting for response, any usefull response would be highly appreciable.
  thaks in adavance

Comment: Do you want to pass text value to php via ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = document.getElementById("txt1").value;

xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?value="+value,true);
```

In gethint.php

```
 echo $_REQUEST['value'];
```

Comment: @cowboy: if Jusnit's answer helped, please accept the answer. That's how you say "thanks" on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this properly, you are trying to get the value of the textbox and pass that to your showhint() method.

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="showhint(document.getElementById('txt1').value)" value="test"/>
```

Then you can accept the value like this:

```
function showhint(value) {
  // use value here
}
```

Hope that helps.